# Using Android Volley to perform a search on a website's search bar

Tags: android, asp.net, http, https, android-volley

So I've been dealing with my problems for some time now with the help of Internet, but I've only had minimal success.

The problem: I'm using Android with the Volley library to try and perform a search from two websites. The websites in question don't have an open API or anything to see how I could perform the searches. I've tried inspecting the HTTP requests in Firefox with the view opening with F12.

[Website 1](https://easiointi.kela.fi/laakekys_app/LaakekysApplication?kieli=en)
Uses HTTPS protocol. I need to search from here using the Vnr number. From the resulting page I would parse the name(s) of the drugs.

[Website 2](http://l%C3%A4%C3%A4keinfo.fi/Search.aspx)
Uses HTTP protocol. From here I would search using the found drug name and I would get the drug description (in Finnish).

For Website 2 I tried the following code, which successfully returns the HTML file of the result page:

```
    RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    String url = "http://www.laakeinfo.fi/Medicine.aspx?m=758&d=2111337&i=ORION+PHARMA_RESILAR_RESILAR+oraaliliuos+3+mg/ml";

    StringRequest request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            Log.d("HTTPTEST", "Response len: " + response.length());
            writeToFile(response);
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Log.d("HTTPTEST", "Error: " + error.getMessage());
        }
    }) {
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
            params.put("i", "Resilar");
            return params;
        }

        @Override
        public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
            params.put("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            return params;
        }
    };

    queue.add(request);
```

Now this works because the URL points straight to where I want it to. If I changed the URL to `"http://www.laakeinfo.fi/Search.aspx"` and in getParams() I'd use instead `params.put("Search1:txtSearch", "Resilar");` (the search bar's contents) it just returns the search page itself.

Now my questions is, is what I'm trying to do possible? I'm not too well in the know with web stuff, but it seems the pages hide the search logic and everything in a way that makes it difficult to perform the searches. If it is indeed possible, how could I go about it? Any hints would be appreciated in this attempt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quick answer is **YES, you can do it!**  ... but it might be not that simple :)

So servers might check many many things in the request and even 'insignificant' data like Accept-Language: header might cause the service to return or not a response.

you have 2 main things you have to check and experiment with and 1 remark:

1) **Headers**

```
    Host: xn--lkeinfo-5waa.fi
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.11; rv:45.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/45.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
DNT: 1
Referer: http://xn--lkeinfo-5waa.fi/Search.aspx
Cookie: ASP.NET_SessionId=mxj22y2oofzwcnmtcen50c45
```

these might change the behavior so you need to experiment there. I would try to put all that I think might be useful or do not understand. Here I would remove just the 'Cookie' and 'Accept-Encoding'.

2) **Params**

```
__EVENTTARGET:"Search1$lbSubmit"
__EVENTARGUMENT:""
__VIEWSTATE:"/wEPDwUKMTc2NzY1NjI3Mg9kFgJmD2QWBAIDD2QWAgIFDxYCHgVjbGFzcwUGYWN0aXZlZAIFD2QWBGYPFgIfAAUJZnJtc2VhcmNoZAICDw8WBh4IQ3NzQ2xhc3MFA2J0bh4EVGV4dAUDSEFFHgRfIVNCAgJkZGQ2BqYJzINvRHYkGXr7+fwtg0L8cQ=="
__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR:"BBBC20B8"
__EVENTVALIDATION:"/wEWBALa8vLKCALQkcCMBAL43fjZDALY7fiNCoNRBovCyGbCM+mhYEACTRYyyeuF"
Search1:txtSearch:"Resilar"
Search1:hdLanguageId:"1"
```

Although 'Search1:txtSearch' seems the obvious one to make a search the other might play part in it to so I would add all of those and remove them 1 by one and try out.

3) (remark) **response 302** this is a post request which does not return a response but rather redirects to one. You have to be careful enable debug logs and check what Volley returns as this response is considered as an error in volley. It might be handled by the HTTP Stack Volley uses but it depends which one is set. If this is the case this will be transparent to volley but otherwise some customization on Volley needs to be done or use another stack. For example android has adopted and baked OkHttp in Android source as the native client actually used by URLConnection. So earlier versions like KitKat would not handle this redirect. The new releases however handles it.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the advice and encouragement! I actually got it working by including everything you said (which was found using the Network Inspector) and dropping the Content-Type. Somehow it messed everything up. Also, since it's a form, I had to use POST instead of GET :)